# SDL delete an image and replace it with the new one

Tags: sdl

I've started SDL just a few days ago and I'm having a problem

I tried to erase an image from the screen and replace it with the new one

here is my logic :

1. load image
2. apply surface, then delay for 1s
3. free old image surface (SDL_FreeSurface())
4. load new image
5. apply surface

The problem is the image is still there. (it didn't get erased, just stacked with the new image)

Answer (score 2):

The screen doesn't work like you think it does.  You cannot "delete" something from a screen buffer, you can only write new things to the screen buffer.  To 'erase' something you need to write the "background" over it.

Some game loops just re-write the entire screen with the background every frame.

This probably belongs over at gamedev.stackexchange.com